# lion: continuous rendering during fullscreen transition

Tags: opengl, osx-lion, fullscreen

What do I have to do to keep rendering with opengl during the transition to/from fullscreen? currently lion crossfades to a white screen and as soon as the transition is finished my own rendering becomes visible again.